# Azure Custom Policy B2C - Orchestration step

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, orchestration

I wanted to know how we can write a policy to show the user a Sign Up button which can direct him to another screen to sign up using the email address. I wrote a custom policy which works with a user with account in the Active directory. For this the first orchestration step lets the user sign in using an email. The step comes back with a message if the user is not found.

After that I am trying to write the second orchestration step which should be executed only if the user was not found in the previous orchestration step.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

The step is not executed even after I get the message that the user was not found. How can I get this working. I would have preferred the user to be shown a sign up button the same screen.

Any ideas?

**Update**: I have a feeling that the alternate flow of not being able to find the user should be handled in the TechnicalProfile and not the orchestration step.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show a sign-in screen which has a link "Sign-up" that allows user to sign-up using SerlfAssertedAttributeProvider? If so, this is how it is done in the LocalAccounts starter pack (copied from `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`):

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already been through the links you have provided before posting here. I wrote my custom policy solution using the <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

Comment: Until you provide more details then, it's not possible to help. For example, what does your UJ look like, what validation profiles are used etc. What is expected behavior and what is actual - i.e. the difference between what you want and what you're getting. Then it's easier to suggest an answer.